# Recycle/repeat a string until reaching a given length and then count a specific letter

Tags: r

My problem is the following:

Say I have a string `abc` and a number `10`. I want to extend the string to be `abcabcabca` (with the additional `a` at the end).

Basically what I am trying to do is extend the characters in a given string `s` by a given number `n` and count the number of occurrences of a certain letter.

I am looking for a better way to carry out the above. I have a function which works but it gives a warning caused by the `cbind()`.

Code/Data:

```
repeatedString <- function(n, s, l){
  split_strings = strsplit(s, '')[[1]]
  make_sequences = seq(from = 1, to = n)
  extend_characters = cbind(split_strings, make_sequences)
  s_seq = extend_characters[,1]
  occurrences = sum(s_seq == l)
  return(occurrences)
}

repeatedString(n = 10, s = "abc", l = "c")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the string and then use `length.out` argument available for `rep` function to extend the string to length `n` by recycling its elements

```
x = "abc"
n = 10
sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(s){
    paste(rep(s, length.out = n), collapse = "")
})
#[1] "abcabcabca"
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed your solution slightly as I want to see things step by step. `repeatedString <- function(n, s, l){
  split_strings = strsplit(s, '')[[1]]
  extended_strings <- rep(split_strings, length.out = n)
  occurrences = sum(extended_strings == l)
  return(occurrences)
}

repeatedString(n = 10, s = "abc", l = "a")`  Is working great!

Answer (score 1):

A different possibility to generate the string could be:

```
n <- 10
x <- c("abc", "abcde", "ab")

substr(strrep(x, (floor(n/nchar(x)) + 1)), 1, n)

[1] "abcabcabca" "abcdeabcde" "ababababab"
```

And then to count the number of occurrence of `a`:

```
x_n <- substr(strrep(x, (floor(n/nchar(x)) + 1)), 1, n)

sapply(x_n, function(x) length(grepRaw("a", x, all = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)))

abcabcabca abcdeabcde ababababab 
         4          2          5
```

A small comparison in terms of performance (just the generation of strings):

```
x <- rep(x, 1000000)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
 tmfmnk = substr(strrep(x, (floor(n/nchar(x)) + 1)), 1, n),
 d.b = sapply(strsplit(x, ""), 
                           function(s) paste(rep(s, length.out = n), collapse = "")),
 times = 5)

Unit: seconds
   expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
 tmfmnk  1.540213  1.568921  1.60646  1.569343  1.669179  1.684643     5
    d.b 15.722021 16.437724 17.05823 17.022109 17.205378 18.903920     5
```